# convert datetime from mysql to human readable string

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a datetime that I get from a mysql table and I would like to display it as a string.It looks like the following and I would like it to look like July 14th 2016 at 5:00 PM.

```
2016-07-14 17:00:00
```

I tried formatting like the following, but it didn't work. How do i get it how I want?

```
    date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
```

Comment: It's not backwards, date_format is datetime::format($object, $format) and says nothing about unix time, also date says it works with timestamp or defaults to time ..

Comment: doh, right. sorry. missed the _format part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to convert the `$date` to Timestamp using something like `strtotime()` perhaps and then pass this as the second argument to PHP's `date()` function. The First Argument would be the `Format` for the Date. This below illustrates it....

```
<?php
    $date   = "2016-07-14 17:00:00";
    $date   =  date('g:ia \o\n l jS F Y', strtotime($date));

    var_dump($date);
    // PRODUCES: '5:00pm on Thursday 14th July 2016'  (length=33);
```

Comment: Documentation: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's [`date_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), but it expects a [date object](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) rather than a string.

> date_format ( DateTimeInterface $object , string $format )

Here's an example using the procedural style:

```
$date_string="2016-07-14 17:00:00";
$date_object=date_create($date_string);
echo date_format($date_object, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
```

Here's an example using the object oriented style:

```
$date_string="2016-07-14 17:00:00";
$date_object=new Datetime($date_string);
echo $date_object->format('g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
```

Output:

> 5:00pm on Thursday 14th July 2016

Answer (score 1):

```
$date=date_create("2016-07-14 17:00:00");
echo date_format($date,'jS F Y \a\t g:ia');
```

Output : 
`14th July 2016 at 5:00pm`

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime

```
<?php
    $datetime = "2016-07-14 17:00:00";

    $dt = new DateTime($datetime);
    echo $dt->format('F jS Y \a\t g:ia');
?>
```

> Output: July 14th 2016 at 5:00pm

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
$mysqlDate = "2016-07-14 17:00:00";
$formatted = date('F dS Y \a\t H:iA', strtotime($mysqlDate));
```

Will display: July 14th 2016 at 5:00PM

Edit: i have forgotten to add the "at"

Comment: Almost the same answer is already given: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38576803/4016757